# Restore default Gnome Shell theme

Tags: gnome, themes, ubuntu-gnome

I use Gnome 3.16 in Ubuntu 15.10, but tried out KDE and Cinnamon yesterday.

Now the windows in Gnome Shell no longer have rounded corners (there are also some other visual differences in the theme):

[image]

I have tried:

- Removing KDE and Cinnamon completely.
- `apt-get install --reinstall gnome-themes-standard`
- `rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*`

But nothing has helped.